# Throwing exception consumes HUGE amount of memory

Tags: c#, .net

I am implementing some retry code that looks likes like so:

```
protected void LoadPSVToContext()
{
    var tokenizedFile = GetTokenizedValuesForFile();

    var retries = 0;
    var retryMax = 5;
    var doDataLoad = true;

    while (doDataLoad)
    {
        try
        {
            LoadData(ref tokenizedFile);
            doDataLoad = false;
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (retries < retryMax)
            {
                retries++;
                _nlog.Info($"Retrying {retries}/{retryMax}");
            }
            else
            {
                _nlog.Error("Max retries exceeded.");
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    _nlog.Info("File sent to database...");
}

public void LoadData(ref string[][] tokenizedFile)
{
    throw new Exception("Test timeout");
}
```

Prior to attempting 'LoadData' for the first time, the App is 95megs in memory.  After the first exception is thrown, the app explodes to 261 megs!  Each retry after that only gets worse and by the time I get to retry 5, my app is at 1.2 Gigs and runs out of memory.  I am not allocating any memory in a loop here and I'm passing everything by reference, so where is all this crazy allocation coming from?  GC.collect() does little to help this problem since the allocation happens so fast that GC is not able to free it before the memory exception.

Help in understanding this would be appreciated.

**Update #1**

A request was made for my GetTokenizedValuesForFile code:

```
public string[][] GetTokenizedValuesForFile()
{
    var recordCount = File.ReadLines(DecryptedFilePath).Count();
    var result = new string[recordCount][];

    using (var parser = new TextFieldParser(DecryptedFilePath))
    {
        parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
        parser.SetDelimiters(Settings.Default.FieldSeperator);
        while (!parser.EndOfData)
        {
            //Processing row
            result[parser.LineNumber - 1] = parser.ReadFields();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Out of desperation, I thought maybe by passing the array without ref that the framework was making a copy of it for the exception details or something, so I wanted to make sure that only a pointer was being passed and not a copy of the entire array (it's very large).

Comment: hoodaticus, can you explain where you see an infinite loop?

Comment: Camilo, by the way, the same memory explosion happens without the ref.

Comment: Wondering if it could be that the data is being assigned to the exception details. Can you post the code to GetTokenizedValuesForFile?

Comment: Take a memory dump and run dumpheap -stat in windbg to see where all your memory is going.

Comment: @Bitfiddler - I simply saw that your line to set doDataLoad = false will never, ever, ever get hit.  I didn't notice that you at least have a retry limit that throws to escape the loop since your control variable is useless.

Comment: Is this all that you are doing and it is going out of memory?  You don't have any code in the LoadData besides the throw exception and it goes out of memory?

Comment: hoodaticus, it will exit, follow the rest of the code... once 5 retries happen it will rethrow the exception and exit.  This is not the problem in the code, but thanks.

Comment: iMortality, yes the behavior with the crazy memory allocation is using this code alone.  In my actual code I would be doing more, but the memory craziness is happening with only the exception being thrown.

Comment: @Bitfiddler you need to put an `@` character before someone's name if you want a person to be notified of your response.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thanks for the tip.  Didn't know that.

Comment: @hoodaticus I have never worked with memory dumps so I'll try that and post back if I have any additional details.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, I have posted the code for the Tokenized Values

Comment: Write a [mcve]. The problem is probably somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

First I'd like to thank everyone for their comments and suggestions.  This is a project I took over from someone else and after everyone's seeming disbelief that something like what I was describing could happen, I realized I must be missing something in the project.

A tiny little file called AspectInfo.cs had me curious so I opened it and noticed a global Logging aspect that applied to the entire application and caught and logged any exception that happened in the project.  Normally I guess this would be a neat trick, except when it's capturing the entire context of the exception and that context happens to include a huge data array.

Commenting out the aspect immediately resolved the memory issue.  So perhaps this might help someone in the future to short circuit their search for problems.

Comment: "Out of desperation, I thought maybe by passing the array without ref that the framework was making a copy". Array is class, so it is passed by reference. Unless you are changing that reference inside the given method pass it without `ref`, because every reader would assume that you use `ref` for its purpose (i.e. changing the reference). Off-topic note, please consider dropping exception because your next problem will be efficiency, other than that it is profiling your code and pinpointing allocation.

Comment: @greenoldman, the exception in the code above was simply to isolate the problem.  In the code I am connecting to a database and for an as-yet unknown reason, the database connection simply times out at random times.  I implemented the retry code and immediately started getting out of memory exceptions so I tried to shave everything down to the minimal amount of code that reproduced the problem.